# Error when parsing JSON Data from my URL

Tags: android, json

I'm developing an android application based on remote database , I found solutions on how to put data in the database but I'm having much problems on getting it back.
When I open the activity that gets the data the app crash. I couldn't localise where the error is in my code!! so here is my code and I hope you can help me .
Thank you.

This is "Acceuil"  class that has 1 button to open "Professors" class.

```js
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


//in this class I'm just defining a button that will open another class to get data from the database.

public class Acceuil extends Activity  {
 
 
 Button b1;
 

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.acceuil);
  
  b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
  
  b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Professors.class);
    startActivity(i);
    
   }
  });
  
  
  
  
  

 }
}
```

This is the "Professors"  class that crashes my app.

```js
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Professors extends Activity {
 
 
 
 //URL to get JSON Array
  private static  String url = "http://waelhamda.host22.com/comments.php";
  
  //JSON Node Names 
  private static final String TAG_USER = "posts";
  private static final String TAG_ID = "last";
  
  
  JSONArray user = null;



     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       
         setContentView(R.layout.professors);
         
   // Creating new JSON Parser
   JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

   // Getting JSON from URL
   JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
   
   try {
    // Getting JSON Array
    user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
    JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);
    
    // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
   
    
    //Importing TextView
    final TextView uid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pro1);
   
    
    //Set JSON Data in TextView
    uid.setText(id);
    

   
  } catch (JSONException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

    

     }


  
     
 }
```

This is the "JSONParser" class.

```js
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;
 
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


 
import android.util.Log;
 
public class JSONParser {
 
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
 
    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {
 
    }
 
    
    
    
   

     public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

      // Making HTTP request
      try {
       // defaultHttpClient
       DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

       HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
       HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
       is = httpEntity.getContent();   

      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
      
      try {
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
         is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       String line = null;
       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
       }
       is.close();
       json = sb.toString();
      } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
      }

      // try parse the string to a JSON object
      try {
       jObj = new JSONObject(json);
      } catch (JSONException e) {
       Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
      }

      // return JSON String
      return jObj;

     }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {
 
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
 
            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
 
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
 
            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
 
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           
 
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
 
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
 
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
 
    }

 
}
```

And finally this is the manifest file of the app.

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wael.enimcommunity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    
    
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key" 
        android:value="AEdPqrEAAAAIdPJ8uLgoiErqlZNYU5_jN_d8O8VPPtfbbF5MRQ" />


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.wael.enimcommunity.Login"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.wael.enimcommunity.Register"
            android:label="@string/app_name"  >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.wael.enimcommunity.Acceuil"
            android:label="@string/app_name"  >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.wael.enimcommunity.JSONParser"
            android:label="@string/app_name"  >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.wael.enimcommunity.GPSTracker"
            android:label="@string/app_name"  >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.wael.enimcommunity.Events"
            android:label="@string/app_name"  >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.wael.enimcommunity.Professors"
            android:label="@string/app_name"  >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.wael.enimcommunity.Portail"
            android:label="@string/app_name"  >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.wael.enimcommunity.Schedule"
            android:label="@string/app_name"  >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I hope those informations are enough to solve my problem. Thanx again my friends.

Comment: Please post your logcat output with the errors you are receiving

Comment: Why don't you start by posting the allegedly faulty JSON message ?

Comment: Sorry my friend but i'm testing on my real device because the emulator didn't work on my laptop .

Comment: For one your web host is adding things to your "json" file, so it is not valid json. Also, your response headers from your server are "text/html; charset=utf-8" They should be json

Comment: @waelbenhamda You can still get logcat output from a real device. And without it, it is very difficult to troubleshoot your issue

Comment: @Zerp sorry but I did never used logcat and I don't know well how to use it (I'm still new on android programming) , I tested the "Professors" class on another app and it did get the data but I don't know why in this one it does not.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Android Studio? Eclipse?

Comment: @zerp I'm using Eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Network operations can involve unpredictable delays. To prevent this from causing a poor user experience, always perform network operations on a separate thread from the UI. The AsyncTask class provides one of the simplest ways to fire off a new task from the UI thread.

[Connecting to the Network](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html)

Comment: Invalid JSON remains invalid JSON, no matter the delay or the user experience.

Answer (score 1):

You are networking in main thread. You need to fix this first.

Use AsyncTask

Example:

```
private TextView uid; // Define global
```

In onCreate

```
uid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pro1);

new MyAsyncTask().execute();
```

Inner class

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

 @Override
 public String doInBackground(Void a) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
                // Getting JSON Array
                user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
                JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);

                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);

                return id;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
 }

 public void onPostExecute(String result) {
    uid.setText(result);
 }

}
```